# ClassCastException while unit test of Firestore snapshot listener

Tags: firebase, kotlin, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, junit

I am trying to cover firestore snapshot listener but got the following exception

```
class kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to class com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration (kotlin.Unit is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration is in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @96897c8)
        java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to class com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration (kotlin.Unit is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration is in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @96897c8)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListener(Query.java:1088)
```

The interesting thing is that while I debug the test it returns the correct mock on listener but not sure while I run it it fails

Here is my test

```
 whenever(fireStoreDbMock.collection("myCollection")).thenReturn(collection)
    whenever(collection.document("myDocument")).thenReturn(document)

    whenever(collection.addSnapshotListener(any())).thenAnswer { invocation ->
        val valueEventListener = invocation.arguments[0] as EventListener<QuerySnapshot>
        val mockedDataSnapshot: QuerySnapshot = mock()
        val list = mutableListOf<DocumentSnapshot>()
        val documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot = mock()
        list.add(documentSnapshot)
        whenever(mockedDataSnapshot.documents).thenReturn(list)
        whenever(documentSnapshot.id).thenReturn("1234")
        valueEventListener.onEvent(mockedDataSnapshot,null)
    }
        remoteDbRepository.getFireStoreData()
```

and here is the function snippet

```
 firestoreDb.collection("myCollection")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ ->
            val allMessages = mutableListOf<MyData>()
            snapshot?.documents?.forEach {
                allMessages.add(
                    MyData(
                        id = it.id
                    )
                )
```

So on logs and debugger I see that it returns me mocked snapshot and I can parse the data. But for some reason it throws that exception